/bin/sh: python: команда не найдена (VS code + Code Runner) - Почему выдает ошибку?
/bin/sh: python: команда не найдена
(VS code + Code Runner + Linux Red Hat)
Добавил строчки в файл - settings.json


    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,



Подскажите пожалуйста почему выдает ошибку?
введите сюда описание изображения



Для начала попробуйте вообще отключить code runner. Расширение python само умеет запускать код.

Причем буквально вчера у вас все нормально без него запускалось, а теперь вы зачем-то решили его установить.

Ищу варианты чистого вывода кода без путей - Это один из них )

Если нужно без путей - запускайте вообще из sh файла. Или добавляйте в начало py файла shebang и делайте его исполняемым. По поводу code runner - не советую его использовать, он например не умеет с виртуальными окружениями работать. Это может доставить больше неудобств в будущем, чем какие-то там пути.

Благодарю за совет добрый человек. Желаю хорошего вечера.

По поводу того, почему выдает ошибку - он пытается выполнять команду python, но у вас такой команды нет, есть python3. Кажется это можно настроить в code runner. Для ubuntu (и наверное debian) есть пакет что-то типа python-is-python3, он вроде бы делает симлинк python на python3 - можно какой-то такой вариант поискать.
